# BLE disconnect and close the Gatt, getConnectionState is STATE_CONNECTED, but device connection is still alive

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

I have a application for controlling multiple Bluetooth LE lamps.

When I want to disconnect all devices at same time, I call BluetoothGatt disconnect, and close from onConnectionStateChange, getConnectionState will return STATE_DISCONNECTED, but sometimes some devices' connection is still alive.

I can see the closed logs.

```
BluetoothGatt: close()

unregisterApp() - mClientIf=xx
```

But I can't see the disconnected log.

```
onReceive: android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED

TrustAgent.Tracker: [BluetoothConnectionTracker] Bluetooth disconnect broadast for xxx
```

I used ReentrantLock to make sure every device only has one Gatt, and executing control functions on main thread by MainThread annotation, but the issue still exists.

How can I fix this issue?

---

Finally, I solved this problem.
The reason is that I can't connect multiple devices at the same time.
So I used a queue to connect the devices one by one.

Comment: I see the same thing sometimes, here´s a discussion btw https://github.com/evothings/cordova-ble/issues/108.

Comment: Thank you, but this issue is different than that.
After I disconnected the device, I can discover again, BluetoothManager told me the device was disconnected, but the device is connection is still alive, and I didn't received the disconnected broadcast message.